# Determine points on line with specific distance from plane

Tags: geometry, vectors, vector-analysis

There is a line $$p: \dfrac{x-1}{2} = \dfrac{y+1}{3} = \dfrac{z+1}{-1}$$
and plane $$\pi : x+y+2z-3=0.$$

I need to find points $T_1, T_2 \in p$. Requirement when finding those points are that they have a set distance from plane $\pi$, with distance being $\sqrt{6}$, and that the points are on the line.

The solution for this problem is
$T_1=\left( \dfrac 13, -2, -\dfrac 23\right)$
$T_2 = \left( \dfrac{25}{3}, 10, -\dfrac{14}{3} \right)$

Problem is I don't have idea how to get there, so I will apreciate any advice/guidance for solving this problem.

**EDIT1**

Equation for distance between point and plane is:

$d(pi,T_\pi')=\dfrac{|AX_0+BY_0+CZ_0+D|}{\sqrt{(A^2+B^2+C^2)}})$

so I get:

$\sqrt6=\dfrac{|X_0+Y_0+2Z_0-3|}{\sqrt6}$
$6=|X_0+Y_0+2Z_0-3|$

since the requirement for parallel planes is: $\dfrac{A_1}{A_2}=\dfrac{B_1}{B_2}=\dfrac{C_1}{C_2}$ I deduced that $A_2=B_2=2C_2$

returning to where I left:

$6=|4X_0-3|$

$4X_0-3=6$
and
$4X_0-3=-6$

$X_01=\dfrac{9}{4}$
and
$X_02=\dfrac{-3}{4}$

Finally I have two planes but I will focus on one because I messed up something:
$\pi .. \dfrac{9}{4}X+\dfrac{9}{4}Y+\dfrac{9}{2}-3=0$

If I fit vector of line direction into this equation we get that $t=\dfrac{10}{9}$
Now if try to fit $t$ back in the equation I will get wrong results since x will be $\dfrac{29}{9}$.

What am I currently missing?

Comment: Are the points $T_1$ and $T_2$ supposed to be on the line?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add that requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ \dfrac{x-1}{2} = \dfrac{y+1}{3} = \dfrac{z+1}{-1} = t$ for some point $(x,y,z)$ on the line $p$.

Then $p(t) = (1+2t, -1+3t, -1-t)$

Using your distance formula, we get
\begin{align}
   \dfrac{|1(1+2t) + 1(-1+3t) + 2(-1-t) - 3|}{\sqrt{(1^2 + 1^2 + 2^2)}} &= \sqrt 6 \\
   |3t-5| &=  6 \\
   3t - 5 &= \pm 6 \\
   t &\in \left\{ -\dfrac 13, \dfrac{11}{3} \right\}
\end{align}

So the points are

$p\left(-\dfrac 13 \right) = T_1$

$p\left( \dfrac{11}{3} \right) = T_2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Giving a plane $\pi$,  with the help of its normal vector, parallel planes at a defined distance $\pi_d$, can be build. Now the intersection of $\pi_d$ with the line gives the solution.

NOTE.

I will present the solution in a slight different notation

$$
L\equiv \cases{
x-1=2\lambda\\
y+1=3\lambda\\
z-1=-\lambda 
}\ \ \Rightarrow p = p_0 + \lambda \vec v\ \ \cases{p = (x,y,z)\\
p_0 = (1,-1,1)\\
\vec v = (2,3,-1)}
$$

and

$$
\Pi \equiv (p-p_1)\cdot \vec n = 0 \Rightarrow \cases{\vec n = (1,1,2)\\ -p_1\cdot \vec n = -3\\
p_1 = (0,1,0)\\
\vec n = (1,1, 2)
}
$$

now

$$
\Pi_d \equiv \left(p-p_1 \pm \frac{\vec n}{||\vec n||}d\right)\cdot\vec n= 0
$$

and

$$
L\cap\Pi_d \equiv \left(p_0 + \lambda \vec v-p_1 \pm \frac{\vec n}{||\vec n||}d\right)\cdot\vec n= 0
$$

hence

$$
\lambda_d = \frac{1}{\vec v\cdot \vec n}\left((p_1-p_0)\cdot\vec n\pm ||\vec n|| d\right)
$$

so the sough points are given by

$$
p_d = p_0 +\lambda_d\vec v
$$

Comment: I tried to do that but I failed somewhere. I put in EDIT1 what have I done. Could you please give me some hint again.

Comment: @LukaMrko Included the developments as required, as a NOTE.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to work with parallel planes, you can use the fact that they have the same normal vector. This means you only need to change the $d$ in the plane equation. So you want to find a plane $x+y+2z+d=0$ such that its distance to $\pi$ is $\sqrt{6}$.

The distance between two planes with the same normal vector is:

$ d=\frac{|d_1-d_2|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}$

So, plugging in the values for this specific problem you get:

$ \sqrt{6}=\frac{|d_1-(-3)|}{\sqrt{6}}=\frac{|d_1+3|}{\sqrt{6}}$

So either $d=-9$ or $d=3$

So, for example, your first plane would be:

$x+y+2z-9=0$

Then,  fitting the vector of line direction into this equation we get that $t=\frac{11}{3}$

Then you get $x=\frac{25}{3}$